# Setting up many to many assocations with Sequelize and Sqlite3

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I have this code here, that I would like to initiate a Many to many connection with, I have the associations set. I do not have foreign keys, as from what I read that is not needed. Where I am stuck here, is how to actually connect the “book” to the “library”. I really would like someone to teach me how to do this instead of just giving me the answer, if that is all possible? Link to the Repo: https://github.com/Corey-Miller85/ManyToMany, The guide I am using to try to teach myself this is, https://sequelize-guides.netlify.com/many-many-associations/
The main part where I get stuck adding a book to the library, according to this article I should now have a method that would allow me to use “Library.addBook()” I have tried this, “Book.addLibrary” and so on with no luck. Does anyone have somewhere I can learn this better, or have someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 0):

why do you think you don't have to set up any keys or foreign keys exactly?  Plus this is an issue... when you use as: library_Book and name it the same on both sides of the relationship.. that doesn't really make good sense...  in Book the as might make more sense like as: LibrariesForBook and in Library maybe something like as:BooksInLibrary so that your getters make sense...  i think you should set up your primary keys and foreign keys and get the parent create working with models.Book.create() or whatever.. and then come back and show what you've done and we can help out with the include for that or another working method